# What's the significance of highlighted Answers in my User Profile?

Tags: support

Can anyone please explain why, in the list of *Answers* in my User Profile, some entries are highlighted?

Comment: May you provide a screenshot?

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I'm afraid I don't know how to post a screenshot here. The effect has changed somewhen in the last few days, though. Previously all Questions in the Answers section were in red, just some were high-intensity red. Now those ones show in black. If I click on a black Question to view what Answers/Comments I made, when I return to the User Profile page that Question will have turned red.

Comment: When edit a question, or an answer, on the top of the text field you will see some icons; the sixth one, the one to the right of the icon showing "101010", is the icon that allows to attach images. Without to know something more, I can guess it's the browser that is showing you the links you didn't visit.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I think you are right. jasper has suggested the same thing in his comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it's not the browser that is showing you the links you didn't yet visited?

In my user profile, the questions with the title in red are the ones I recently visited. As the different color used for those links depends from the browser, other users could see in red a link you see in black, or vice versa; you can check this looking at [my user profile](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/252/kiamlaluno).

I don't remember until when those links are rendered in a different color, though.

[image: screenshot]